# Django compressor fails to compress coffeeScript files in production

Tags: django, heroku, coffeescript, django-compressor

I use stylus and coffeeScript with django compressor, and It works perfectly in Dev. Here is my Jade template:

```
- load compress
!!! 5
html
    head
        title Super Page
        - compress css
        link(rel='stylesheet',type='text/stylus',href='{{STATIC_URL}}styles/base.styl')
        link(rel='stylesheet',type='text/stylus',href='{{STATIC_URL}}styles/style.styl')
        - endcompress
        - compress js
        script(type='text/coffeescript',src='{{STATIC_URL}}app/coolscript.coffee')
        script(type='text/coffeescript',src='{{STATIC_URL}}app/evencooler.coffee')
        - endcompress
    body
        block content
```

For deployment I use Heroku and Amazon S3 for static files. Once deployed I visit the site and the page loads fine and styles look as expected but the scripts are not working.
Checking the `<head>` I see the styles were compressed into one css file but the coffeeScript files were not. The browser is fetching the CS source files:

```
<script type="text/coffeescript" src="http://supercoolapp.s3.amazonaws.com/static/app/coolscript.coffee"></script>
<script type="text/coffeescript" src="http://supercoolapp.s3.amazonaws.com/static/app/evencooler.coffee"></script>
I
```

**It was working before**, I had this problem once but I don't remember what was the cause, I think the compile process  is failing silently and I don't know how to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a not so easy to find coffeeScript problem. In my machine I was using coffeescript v1.4.X and heroku was using v1.6.3. I had a `for own in array` that v.1.4 allowed(it shouldn't) but v1.6.3 didn't(actually it didn't show the right error but a different one which is a bug shown [here](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/3053)).

Anyway I solved the problem fixing the coffee file but I still think its a compressor error not to fail in production ignoring errors without giving any clue of what happened.